# How to create a group of threads via ACE library and wait for it to finish

Tags: ace

I'm trying to create a group of threads and wait for it to finish. As far as I understand, I should use ace_thread_manager::spawn_n() function, but I don't know how to wait for all the threads of the group to finish. Can anyone refer me to a simple code sample that demonstrates this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can find this describe in the ACE C++ Network Programming Volume 1 book (see http://www.remedy.nl/opensource/ace.html) chapter 9. You can find the example code if this book examples/C++NPv1 as part of the ACE distribution.